# an expression meaning "to switch to (a less expensive product)"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there an expression, a phrasal verb or otherwise, that means "to switch to (a less advanced, expensive, etc., product or service)" because one doesn't have as much money as one used to or because one wants to save money?

Comment: Change down can mean to switch to the lower rated service, among other meanings. It doesn't have the financial side that you want.

Comment: I cannot find the relevant sense of "change down" in dictionaries.

Comment: I thought I had come across it, but see what others say. Another possibility is downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

"Downgrade" is used in this situation.

> We've decided to downgrade to the basic plan because the luxury plan was costing too much money.

Comment: How about "go downmarket/downscale with the basic plan"?